# Problema ao usar a Função free() na linguagem C. A função não limpa o lixo de memória

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int l, c, tam;

void dimensiona(int *vet, int lin, int col){
    l = lin;
    c = col;
    vet = (int*) malloc(sizeof(vet));
    vet = (int*)malloc(l*c*sizeof(int));
}

void adicionaelemento(int *vet, int val, int lin, int col){
    vet[((lin-1)*c)+(col-1)]= val;
}

int buscaelemento(int *vet, int i, int j){
    return vet[((i-1)*c)+(j-1)];
}

int imprime(int *vet, int i, int c){
    for(int i = 1; i<=l; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j<=c; j++){
            //printf("%d\t", vet[((i-1)*c)+(j-1)]);
            printf("%d\t", *(vet+((i-1)*c)+(j-1))); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void zeramatriz(int *vet){
    free(*vet);
    vet = NULL;
}

int main(){
    int *vet;
    dimensiona(&vet, 3, 3);
    zeramatriz(&vet);
    adicionaelemento(&vet, 15, 1, 2);
    adicionaelemento(&vet, 25, 2, 1);
    adicionaelemento(&vet, 45, 3, 3);
    imprime(&vet, l, c);
    zeramatriz(&vet);
    printf("O elemento que esta na linha 2 coluna 2 eh: %d ", buscaelemento(&vet, 3, 3));

}
´´´
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 3):

Seu programa tem muitos erros ainda.

Talvez devesse escrever aos poucos, em torno dos dados, e ir testando tudo.

#### Das primeiras 12 linhas

```
    int l, c, tam;

void dimensiona(int* vet, int lin, int col)
{
    l   = lin;
    c   = col;
    vet = (int*)malloc(sizeof(vet));
    vet = (int*)malloc(l * c * sizeof(int));
}
```

Não declare essas variáveis aí. Declaradas soltas aí fora de `main()` ou de qualquer função elas se tornam globais, válidas por toda a execução do programa, e isso é um desastre em termos de manutenção e dificulta tudo.

Se `dimensiona()` vai fazer o simples e alocar um vetor de inteiros com um certo número de linhas e colunas faça isso e RETORNE o endereço do vetor.

Que pretende reutilizando o ponteiro logo depois de alocar?

```
    vet = (int*)malloc(sizeof(vet));
    vet = (int*)malloc(l * c * sizeof(int));
```

Não faz sentido. Vai perder o acesso à primeira área alocada.

Se `vet` é uma matriz de `int` com `lin` linhas e `col` colunas sabe que o tamanho dela vai ser `sizeof(int) * lin * col`.

Algo assim já serviria:

```
int* Dimensiona(int l, int c)
{
    return malloc( l * c * sizeof(int));
}
```

Não use `void`: retorne os endereços.

Se o seu dado é a matriz X x Y então pode ser mais simples definir uma `struct` com os campos e o ponteiro e usar só um argumento.

Comment: Obrigado, revi todo o meu código e arrumei bastante coisa mesmo kkk, infelizmente tenho que fazer o programa meio que dessa forma, o professor pediu para ser feito assim, de fato usar struct facilitaria, mas como disse antes, não posso usar por enquanto. Muito obrigado pelo tempo e pela atenção que dedicou ao meu problema!